# Doing a database lookup in formatting expression

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

Where it says "blob_curr = 1" I need to do a check to see if the object id exists in another table. I have no idea how to do this. This is an application that was written several years ago and I am a co-op student who was asked to make some changes to it so I have very limited knowledge of this environment. This is Powerbuilder 9.0 if that helps.

[image: image description]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here:

1) You can update your datawindow query to include an additional field that returns whether the item exists in the other table (scalar subquery comes to mind depending on what database you are using).  Then your datawindow expression just checks this column - This is the preferred solution

2) In a datawindow expression, you can also call global user defined functions that you have created.  So you would create a new function (File->New->PB Object Tab->Function), that takes an id as its incoming argument, performs the lookup in the other table and then returns the result.  Then within the datawindow expression you can now call this function directly to see if it exists in that table.

The first approach will probably be the most efficient database-wise.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I was kind of expecting not to get anything from this.

Comment: Be warned that expressions are re-evaluated on many events (e.g. scrolling of the DataWindow control), so going across the network to the database in a global function from an expression may cause some serious performance hits. Expressions may include factors like First/Last row on the visible page, row with focus, etc..., so expressions are re-evaluated frequently. If your database is "close" from a network perspective, and you have good response time, this may not be an issue. Option 1 will be the safer choice.

Comment: I ended up pushing myself a little harder to learn how this mess works and implemented the change in an option 1 style fix. This has been a very educational experience for me as a programmer.