# Database select within a Powerbuilder function

Tags: powerbuilder

I have attached an image of my function so far. I highlighted the portion that obviously isn't going to work. I am trying to find out the powerbuilder code that will provide the same functionality as that select statement.

[image: picture]

[This question is a followup from this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996380/doing-a-database-lookup-in-formatting-expression)

Answer (score 2):

This would approximate the first conditional statement

```
int ll_count

if typeInd = "T" then 

  select count(object_ident_no)
    into :ll_count
    from rendtn
   where object_ident_no = :objectidin
  using SQLCA;

end if

return (ll_count > 0)
```

I'm assuming that `SQLCA` is your connection in my query.

One thing that stands out is your datatype of `integer` for the objectidin.  In PowerBuilder `Integer` datatypes only hold the range of -32768 to +32767 (16 bit signed integers).  So typically for representing an ID field in the database, you would want to use `Long` (32 bit signed integer) that goes from -2147483648 to +2147483647.  This is more like what you see for an `int` in a language like Java.  It is easy to exhaust 32,000 id's pretty quickly in a database.

Comment: When I try this I get an error of "Cannot compile without valid database signon" ... Good call on the Long variable btw

Comment: @jaredw:  When compiling inline sql, PB tries to validate the objects against the database (table names, column names, etc).  If you don't have a connection open to the database this will fail.  Somewhere in the options in the IDE you can turn this off, but I'm not seeing it offhand.  Look through your options in the IDE and see if you can find a setting about compiling and the database connection.

Comment: @jaredw:  Actually I may be mistaken about being able to disable the validation.  You will need to set up a profile to your database in the database painter (Tools->Database Profile...)

Comment: I created a profile to my database and it works, thank you so much for your help Dougman. Just to clarify, in the expression builder would I simply do something like this: gf_objectexistscheck(object_ident_no,  blob_type_cd)?

Comment: @jaredw: Yep, that should do it.  You would just treat it like any boolean conditional in your expressions in the builder.